# Fisher's Derviation of t Distribution

Tags: density-function, t-distribution

I was looking for a geometrical explanation of degrees of freedom and how they are determined by "the rank of a certain quadratic form", which is the definition my Professor gives but did not prove.

I came across the paper "A Survey of the Theory of Small Samples" by Paul R. Rider in Annals of Mathematics (1930) in which the author follows Fisher's Derivation of the t-statistic in "Frequency Distribution of the Values of the Correlation Coefficient in Samples from an Indefinitely Large Population"(https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring05/sta215/lec/Fish1915.pdf).

The argument presented there is as follows. $P = (x_1,...,x_n)$ is regarded as the rectangular coordinates of a point in N-dimensional Euclidean space. $X \sim iid N(m,\sigma^2)$, so the probability that the sample will lie in the element of volume $dv = dx_1dx_2...dx_n$ is $(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2}e^{-ns^2/2\sigma^2}e^{-n(\bar{x}-m)^2/2\sigma^2}dv$. It is then shown that $P$ must lie on an $(n-1)$ dimensional hypersphere orthogonal to the line $x_1 = x_2 = ... x_n$. There is a diagram of this relationship on page 4 of the Fisher paper. It is then stated that the volume element $dv$ is proportional to $s^{n-2}dsd\bar{x}$.

It's the derivation of the "volume element" that I don't fully understand. I know that the volume of an $(n-1)$ dimensional sphere in n dimensions is proportional to $r^{n-1}$, where $r$ is the radius, so I'm guessing its related to this. More generally what I assume is going on is that the probability mass lies in an $(n-1)$ dimensional subset defined by $\bar{x}$ and $s$. In order to derive a pdf in terms of those variables we need to make some sort of transformation to ensure that the joint pdf integrates to 1. i.e. if we integrate this pdf over the set of the $(n-1)$ dimensional hypersphere we should get 1.

If someone could help me understand the derivation of the volume element, and specifically why it depends on $d\bar{x}$ since the volume of the sphere only depends on its radius, this would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I have no background in measure theory or graduate level math.